# Magento 2: compile - Class Not_Existing_Class does not exist

Tags: magento2, cli, setup-di-compile

I have below error while I am compiling the Magento Store. it took very long time and finally gave this error.

> **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $fileItem->getRealPath())) {
```

to

```
if (preg_match($pattern, str_replace('\\', '/', $fileItem->getRealPath()))) {
```

Check this [Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e07ce7367563d1ffbb693824621e43c9f0f92cb0), Fixed by Magento.